# Storing data in a single varaible using coutvector in omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I am recording the data in omnet++ using the coutVector method the problem I am facing is instead of every time it stores the value in the variable it basically creates a new variable of the same name and stores the data value into it at that instance. my question how to store all the data values in a single variable? At the end of the simulation, I have data in the .vec file but it is 100 variables of the same name and each contains each instance of data in time, I want to make one variable contain all the data.
in header file I define,

```
protected:
    cOutVector variable;
```

in .cc file

```
variable.setName("Reward");
variable.record(new_var);
```

That is of my code look like, One thing to clear is that This .cc file will run in each instance of simulation time. Here is the screeshot[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by 'one variable containing all data'? If you have a `.vec` file where each `record()` call puts out a value (assigned to the same variable name) then you essentially have **one variable** (with that name) associated with all the data.

Comment: I edited the question and add the screenshot, so here a variable name is a reward but it stores each instance value at a time, I want it to be an array that stores all the values in a single Reward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not visible on your screenshot, but if you widen the *Module* column a bit, you will probably see, that each row and so each variable named `Reward` belongs to a different module. So you most likely call the `.record()` method only once for each of your modules. The result is correct in the sense that each module must have its own `Reward` variable.